# Unable to scrape the URL as i contains #(URI fragment) using Python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, fragment, uri

I facing the same problem. How can I **scrape** the below-mentioned URL?

```
start_urls = [ 'https://onlinelibrary.ectrims-congress.eu/ectrims/#!*menu=6*browseby=3*sortby=2*media=3*ce_id=1428' ]
```

the response I am getting is

```
Crawled (200) <GET https://onlinelibrary.ectrims-congress.eu/ectrims/?_escaped_fragment_=%2Amenu%3D6%2Abrowseby%3D3%2Asortby%3D2%2Amedia%3D3%2Ace_id%3D1428%3E> (referer: None) ['cached']
```

But unfortunately, I am unable to extract the data(response.xpath) as it is giving me the null values. This is because when I clicked the response URL it doesn't seem to give me the exact URL from which I wanted to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

**Website**

Checking the website you can see the content which you want to grab is driven by JavaScript which increases the chances of loading the data through API end-point by making AJAX requests. Using chrome dev tools, you can check there are 5 requests loaded in XHR. But, this API `https://onlinelibrary.ectrims-congress.eu/ectrims/listing/events/banners` will give you desired data after passing the required parameters which is headers, cookies & body in Scrapy.

**Code**

```
from scrapy import Request

class Ectrims(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'library'

    headers = {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
        "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Origin": "https://onlinelibrary.ectrims-congress.eu",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Referer": "https://onlinelibrary.ectrims-congress.eu/ectrims/",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
    }

    cookies = {
        "PHPSESSID": "if994kqobo2l80nk1ki7q233i5",
        "_ga": "GA1.2.212877690.1624208120",
        "_gid": "GA1.2.291339791.1624208120",
        "intercom-id-aucjjau5": "bdcafc49-97d0-42fb-b61e-46c74cfed3b0",
        "cp_user_200": "{\"1\":0}"
    }

    body = 'menu=6&browseby=3&sortby=2&media=3&ce_id=1428&getpage=1'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://onlinelibrary.ectrims-congress.eu/ectrims/listing/events/banners'
        yield Request(url=url, method='POST', cookies=self.cookies, headers=self.headers, body=self.body, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.body)
```